# Spring amqp: Remove all bindings for specific queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, spring-amqp

Is there a way to remove all bindings for specific queue using spring-amqp?

There's a workaround, first delete a queue, and then redeclare it

```
amqpAdmin.deleteQueue("testQueue");
amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue("testQueue"));
```

but this is pretty ugly solution and I'd like to avoid it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [REST API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#management-template) to list the bindings and `amqpAdmin.removeBinding()` for those you want to remove.

**EDIT**

Here's the code using a Java 8 `Stream` - you can do the same thing by iterating over the list if you are not using Java 8...

```
RabbitManagementTemplate rmt = new RabbitManagementTemplate("http://localhost:15672/api/", "guest", "guest");
rmt.getBindings().stream()
    .filter(b -> b.getDestination().equals("q1") && b.isDestinationQueue())
    .forEach(b -> {
        System.out.println("Deleting " + b);
        amqpAdmin.removeBinding(b);
    });
```

Result:

```
Deleting Binding [destination=q1, exchange=, routingKey=q1]
Deleting Binding [destination=q1, exchange=ex1, routingKey=foo]
Deleting Binding [destination=q1, exchange=ex2, routingKey=foo]
```

(when q1 was bound to the default exchange and 2 others).

The `RabbitAdmin amqpAdmin` is used to do the deletes.

Comment: I need to remove all bindings for specific queue it's not known what bindings are related to the queue

Comment: This is solid answer, though it does not rely on AMQP protocol. I use qpid and rabbitmq interchangeably, so I'll have to write different implementation for qpid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The amqp protocol (0.9.1) does not have a command (method) to list bindings.