# Spring AMQP: remove old bindings and queues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I’m using Spring AMQP and Spring Boot `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations in order to create all required queues, exchanges and bindings.

```java
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new Queue("my_old_queue", true, false, false);
}

@Bean
public Exchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("MY_OLD_EXCHANGE");
}

@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue())
                         .to(exchange())
                         .with("old_binding")
                         .noargs();
}
```

But I’ve faced with a problem of upgrading my topology:

1. I wanna add a new queue/binding/exchange
2. And remove an old queue/binding/exchange (even if it was durable entity).

Does some annotation exists for removing or unbinding (like `@Unbind`)?
I’ve seen the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275135/spring-amqp-remove-all-bindings-for-specific-queue) where `RabbitManagementTemplate`  was suggested, but it’s a completely different way of configuration - I wanna keep everything in the single @Configuration class and use annotations or config beans only (is it possible?).
Does some common pattern exists for creating/removing and updating rabbit topology (maybe I missed something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete entities with annotations or configuration, use the `RabbitAdmin.delete*()` methods to remove them like in that answer - the management template was used to list the bindings, the `RabbitAdmin` (`amqpAdmin`) does the removals.

Comment: Is there any concept like Flyway for RabbitMQ migrations?